# Vb coding if statement

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code:

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
     ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
     If ProgressBar1.Value = 99 Then
         MessageBox.Show("This is the text", "This is the title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
     End If
```

After it shows the message box, I want it to continue with code like this:

I want to go on with:

```
If Result = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
    MsgBox("You clicked YES!", , Title)
Else
    MsgBox("You clicked NO!", , Title)
End If
```

I got that second part from another program, but I can't get it to work in this context.

Comment: VBA, VB6 and VB.NET are three different languages. Please use only the relevant tag

Comment: What does the MsgBox in the first snippet have to do with the Timer?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 4):

The `MessageBox.Show` method returns a `DialogResult`, which is very similar to the old `VbMsgBoxResult` enum that is returned by `MsgBox`.  So, you could just do something like this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
     ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
     If ProgressBar1.Value = 99 Then
         Dim result As DialogResult
         result = MessageBox.Show("This is the text", "This is the title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
         If Result = DialogResult.Yes Then
             MessageBox.Show("You clicked YES!", Text)
         Else
             MessageBox.Show("You clicked NO!", Text)
         End If             
     End If
```

Comment: Or just: `MessageBox.Show($"You clicked {result}", Title)`

Comment: True.  Though, that's only if showing that simplistic message box really is the desired action.  I assumed that the important part of the question was how to check the result in the `If` statement, not in how to show the secondary message, since it's rather pointless and almost certainly a placeholder used as an example.

Comment: It says Tiltle is not declared

Comment: Ah.  Right.  Sorry about that.  I fixed it.  In pre-.NET VB, `Title` would have referred to the caption of the form.  In .NET WinForms (which is presumably what you're using), the equivalent property is called `Text`.  Regardless, you can pass any string in it's place (e.g. `MessageBox.Show("You clicked YES!", "Hello World")`) or even no title at all (e.g. `MessageBox.Show("You clicked YES!")`).

Answer (score 0):

Using this simple solution will solve your problem. Although it is possible to do this using If Else Statement but in your case Select Case is a good solution too.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
   ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 99 Then
        Select Case MessageBox.Show("This is the text", "This is the title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            Case DialogResult.Yes
                MsgBox("You clicked YES!", , "Title")
            Case DialogResult.No
                MsgBox("You clicked NO!", , "Title")
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please mark it as an answer and upvote it if this worked for you.